# How to update/create column in pandas based on values in a list

Tags: python, pandas

So, here is my dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
cols = ['Name','Country','Income']
vals = [['Steve','USA',40000],['Matt','UK',40000],['John','USA',40000],['Martin','France',40000],]
x = pd.DataFrame(vals,columns=cols)
```

I have another list:

```
europe = ['UK','France']
```

I want to create a new column 'Continent' if x.Country is in europe

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Or you can using `isin` directly

```
x['New Column']='Not Europe'
x.loc[x.Country.isin(europe),'New Column']='Europe'

Out[612]: 
     Name Country  Income  New Column
0   Steve     USA   40000  Not Europe
1    Matt      UK   40000      Europe
2    John     USA   40000  Not Europe
3  Martin  France   40000      Europe
```

Answer (score 15):

You need [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with condition with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
x['Continent'] = np.where(x['Country'].isin(europe), 'Europe', 'Not Europe')
print (x)
     Name Country  Income   Continent
0   Steve     USA   40000  Not Europe
1    Matt      UK   40000      Europe
2    John     USA   40000  Not Europe
3  Martin  France   40000      Europe
```

Comment: Nice solution as usual, allthemore, using `timeit` it seems pretty efficient compared to indexing with `x.loc[x.Country.isin(europe),'Continent']='Europe'`

Comment: I try test it, give me a sec.

Comment: Yes, it is 2 times faster in large df. I get `100 loops, best of 3: 9.62 ms per loop` and `10 loops, best of 3: 23.4 ms per loop`. I test it in `100000 rows`