# python, Iterate through a dataframe and check if a value from a list exist in a column in that dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains a column with different submarkets from a city. I need to iterate through that column and check if a value in that row matches any of the entries that could be in the list. that list will then be added as a column to the original dataframe

```
submarket_list = [ 'South Financial District', 'Financial District', South of Market]

submarket_check = []

for index,row in test_df.iterrows():
    for j in submarket_list:
        if row['Submarket'] == j:
            submarket_check.append("yes")
        else:
            submarket_check.append("No")
test_df['Submarket Check'] = submarket_check
test_df
```

Comment: `test_df['Submarket Check']  = np.where(test_df["Submarket"].isin(submarket_list), 'yes', 'No')` Examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45921117/15497888) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19913845/15497888) (`import numpy as np` )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
test_df["Submarket"].isin(submarket_list)
```

will give you a column of booleans.  It's all you need